# Keras GridSearchCV- get history of epochs of all models

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network, keras, grid-search

I know how to get history of Best Estimator from gridSearchCV on Keras. But what if I want to get those histories of all epochs of all possible combination of hyperparameters.

Not just mean score. but all accuracies...